# why namespace types should not depend on nested namespaces types?

Tags: c#, namespaces

In .Net naming guidelines ([http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/893ke618(v=vs.71).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/893ke618%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)) there is this statement:

"A nested namespace should have a dependency on types in the containing namespace. For example, the classes in the System.Web.UI.Design depend on the classes in System.Web.UI. However, the classes in System.Web.UI do not depend on the classes in System.Web.UI.Design."

I would like to know: why?

Comment: Have you had any luck finding additional information on this guideline? I feel like it was created without any supporting information. Looking back at all of my past projects, I violate this guideline every time. I understand the guideline. For example, I have `Product.Business.Product.IEnumerable<Module> Modules { get; }` that depends on `Module` in `Product.Business.Modules`, which violates the guideline and would require me to move `Module` to the parent namespace.

Comment: Not so far, still does make too much sense to me.

Answer (score 7):

Because it makes sense when you think about it.

Let me explain with a small example:

> A **knife-blade** for example needs a **handle** for it to be a
>   "knife".
>
> But a handle **doesn't** need a knife-blade to be a handle, correct?

```
using KitchenSet;
using KitchenSet.Knives; // This is where your knives (what uses Blades) would live.
using KitchenSet.Knives.Blades; // The actual blades.
```

Comment: So if I have a "handle" class in the namespace and a nested namespace "Blades" with a lot of Blade types to be used with my handle, what would be a better way to organize?

Comment: @bcsanches: I'd like to know that too (because I do similar things); perhaps you should add that to your question as an example?

Comment: @bcsanches: See my edit. Does that make it easier to understand?

Comment: @SergioTapia Sometimes I have a `Knife` factory in `KitchenSet.Knives` which uses implementation types in `KitchenSet.Knives.Blades`; would it be better to have the factory elsewhere?

Comment: In my understanding, a type KitchenSet.Knives would depends on types inside KitchenSet.Knives.Blades, right? If so, is not this that msdn tells us to avoid?

Comment: My style is I'll have a `Blades` base type (interface or abstract) in `Kitchen.Knives` then all the various implementations (Butcher, Paring, Butter) in `Kitchen.Knives.Blades` for organization.

Comment: @ChrisSinclair: That's my style as well. +1

Answer (score 0):

This is a wise rule, because classes defined in the System.Web.UI namespace are visible for classes defined in the System.Web.UI.Design, but classes defined in the System.Web.UI.Design namespace are not visible for classes defined in the System.Web.UI namespace. It is necessary to add a using statement (Imports in VB.NET) in the latter case.

Comment: But when I read the recommendation in msdn, It feels like I am missing some fundamental design guideline or good practice.